# Stripe name on card when creating customer

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Using [stripe/stripe-php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) I have the following code to create a new stripe customer with a card.

```
//CREATE NEW STRIPE CUSTOMER
$stripe_customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
    "source"            => Input::get('stripeToken'),
    "email"             => $this->user->email
));
```

I want to add a name property for the card, how do I modify my existing code to do this?

Comment: Add a `customer` element? https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the above code, I simple added the "name" key and associated value to the array used when creating the stripe token.